# Ships are _____ by giant engines

Tags: word-choice, exam-questions

> Ships are _____ by giant engines.

Which is the best word to fill in the given blank from below given options ?

A) sailed

B) Dragged

C) Pulled

D) Driven

Comment: You should explain which options you are able to eliminate, and which ones you can't, and why you are having trouble deciding between them. This question shows no effort by you.

Comment: Here is an example of a question that has the explanation @Tᴚoɯɐuo is advising you to add: https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/85042/ Explaining which choices you know are incorrect is respectful of the people who might answer your question, because it prevents them from wasting their time explaining something you already know.

Comment: @ColleenV Thankyou, I will keep it in mind next time I post anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Driven** is the correct choice.

*Dragged* and *pulled* don't work as a ship's engines are not in front of the ship itself but are one with the ship. *Sailed* doesn't work as *sailed* implies that the engines control the navigation of the ship. Engines merely provide power, and do not have any bearing on the direction the ship takes other than forward.

While *driven* can also carry a similar definition to the one I've described for *sailed*, it can also take a less active meaning.

[drive](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/drive) (Merriam-Webster)

> 3a. to impart a forward motion to by physical force

So in this case, the engines impart the forward motion through force onto the ship.